# Vagrant port forwarding not working (not using loopback)

Tags: networking, centos, vagrant, portforwarding

```
 Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "jhcook/centos7"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 30000, host: 30000

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
end
```

when I ssh into the vm and run 
`sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 30000`  it outputs `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 30000 ...` (so no loopback port)

yet from my host machine (macosx) i cant get to the port..eg

```
->curl 192.168.33.10:30000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.33.10 port 30000: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure whats going on here or where the connection is being blocked? From the VM or form my host?

Comment: What does `ifconfig` from within the VM show?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nJ6QQqiY

Comment: Off topic. Try superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok so I figured out these commands fixed it.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```